# Proof Closer String/Consensus String/Center String is NP-hard

Tags: np-complete, np, strings, p-vs-np

Given are n gene sequences (words over the alphabet {A, T, C, G}), each of length m. Find a gene sequence (of length m) that minimizes the maximum distance to all given gene sequences. Here, distance is measured as the number of positions at which the sequences differ.

Show that the following problem is not efficiently solvable, unless P = NP.

After I did some research I discovered that this is the Closer String/Consensus String/Center String Problem under the hamming distance.
To solve this problem in my opinion you have to show that Closer String is NP-hard.

Is there any easy reduction proof for this? I only find some hard to understand paper for that. Thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to others to [edit] your post to provide a full reference for the paper you have found so far.